# Databricks: reading data with .snappy.parquet extension

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, parquet, snappy

I have a table with .snappy.parquet extension.

```
data= 'part-001-36b4-7ea3-4165-8742-2f32d8643d-c000.snappy.parquet'
```

I would like to read this and I tried the following:

```
table = spark.read.load(data, format='delta')
```

When I try with the above syntaxy, I am getting the following error.
`` AnalysisException: A partition path fragment should be the form like `part1=foo/part2=bar`. The partition path: part-001-36b4-7ea3-4165-8742-2f32d8643d-c000.snappy.parquet ``.

and

```
table = spark.read.parquet(data)
```

When I try with the above, I am getting this error: `AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected`.

Answer (score 1):

Your parquet was probably generated with partitions, so you need to read the entire path where the files and metadata of the parquet partitions were generated

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/path/where/file/is/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using pandas for this specific task, I've found success in the past reading snappy parquet files like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet(data)
```